# What's the difference between Samma Sambuddho and Buddho

Tags: the-buddha

Both are in the nine qualities of the Buddha but I can't see a distinctive difference.  Is there supposed to be a distinctive difference or are these qualities an example of repetition?

Comment: By Buddho do you mean a Paccekabuddha?

Comment: @konrad1 these are the 2nd and 8th qualties of the Buddha,  but they seem so similar as to note need to be separate to my understanding.

Comment: I answered before you reply, check to see if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Visuddhimagga in its description of the contemplation of the attributes of the Buddha:

> Vism. XII
>
> 26. He  is  fully  enlightened  (sammásambuddha)  because  he  has  discovered (buddha) all things rightly (sammá) and by himself (sámaí).
>
> ...
>
> 52. He is enlightened (buddha) with the knowledge that belongs to the fruit of liberation, since everything that can be known has been
>       discovered (buddha) by him.

So the tittle Samasambuddho refers specifically to the Buddha's attainment as the result of self effort, and the title Buddho refers to the attainment itself.

Also, the term Buddho refers to any being that has seen the truth, so a Paccekabuddha is one who attains enlightenment on their own but doesn't teach, and if I'm not too mistaken an Arahat can technically be called an Anubuddha, meaning one who attains enlightnenment through following the teaching of a Sammasambuddha.

Comment: If a samma-sambuddha is alive in the world, and another person becomes fully enlightened without a teacher, and goes on to teach the Dhamma while the first samma-sambuddha is still alive, is he also a samma-sambuddha?

Comment: @qweilun According to the tradition of the Theravada school and the schools related to it (the Dharmaguptaka and Sarvastivada schools) there can only be one Sammasambuddha at a time, so following this interpretation one of them would have to either become a Paccekabuddha or postpone attainment to a later life. According to some other early schools (I think the Lokottaravada maybe) it is possible to have multiple sammasambuddhas at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

According to Theravada tradition, there are 2 types of Buddhas.

1- Samma Sambuddha (full enlighted Buddha), is the type of Buddha that teaches the Dhamma, they are very rare, previous one was the Buddha Kassapa, current one is Shakyamuni Buddha (also known as Gotama Buddha) and the next one will be Maytrea Buddha.

2- Paccekabuddha or private Buddhas, 99% of Buddhas are private Buddhas, they attained enlightment, but not in a degree that they can teach the Dhamma, teaching the Dhamma requires a very special development of the mind.